# Why std::vector<bool> does not specialize the compare function?

Tags: c++, vector

I know that `std::vector<bool>` is a space-efficient specialization of `std::vector` for the type `bool`. I look up the clang and gcc  implementation and find that they  just use the underlying storage type `unsigned long` to store the 64 `bool` elements at once, but why they didn't specialize the compare function such as `operator<`?

As you see the following code, they just use `std::lexicographical_compare` to compare two `vector<bool>`, which is inefficient:

```
template <class Allocator>
bool operator< (const vector<bool, Allocator>& x, const vector<bool, Allocator>& y)
{
    return std::lexicographical_compare(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.end());
}
```

If you use the underlying storage type to store the 64 `bool` elements, why not compare them at once just according to the machine endianness?

Comment: Maybe you could contribute a patch. There is already a [defect report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50160) on gcc's bugzilla.

Comment: [Howard Hinnant wrote a piece that touches on this](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool).

Comment: @user4581301 [The original](http://howardhinnant.github.io/onvectorbool.html) (with less weird picture of him, and better format).

Comment: Since almost everyone uniformly agrees that `std::vector<bool>` specialization was a spectacular fiasco, people are likely not to be interested in performance improvements.

Comment: `operator<()` for all specialisations of `std::vector` is specified as being equivalent to using `std::lexicographical_compare`. Using a specialisation for `std::vector<bool>` that compares the underlying storage would add other requirements, like zeroing unused bits in the underlying representation (impost on all operations on a vector) versus `operator<()` excluding those bits in the comparison, etc. A simpler explanation, however, is that `std::vector<bool>` is designed for SPACE efficiency not speed, so the gcc/clang developers probably didn't see the point of optimising for speed.